# Ubuntu 18.04. No analog sound detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, 18.04

I have asked a question 2 days ago that sound cards are not detected on my machine. [Ubuntu 18.04 No Sound Card detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032431/ubuntu-18-04-no-sound-card-detected)

I restored the BIOS settings to default and the card reappeared but with a new problem.

It only shows Digital (HDMI) outputs and it does not show Analog outputs.

The output of `aplay -l` :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I can find Analog options in pulseaudio. I tried adding the line `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as it was a suggested fix but it did not work.

[Here is my Alsa info](https://pastebin.com/NqC4uad1)

Any help would be appreciated.