# Sound cards not detected after update to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Both my external speakers (via headphone jack) and monitor speakers (via displayport) worked prior to the update, though I remember having to fiddle when I first installed Ubuntu. Since the upgrade, the only sound output device that displays is a Unix FIFO sink from my chrome-remote-desktop.

I've tried everything the internet mentioned, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong and I feel as though I've expended all of the old recommendations I've found here and elsewhere. As you'll see below, my sounds cards are present but somehow not being detected by the system/pavucontrol, so my best guess is there's some config file that's hanging out that I haven't been able to find and purge. Any suggestions are appreciated--I'm at my wits end and just want to watch Netflix... :)

My `/proc/asound/cards` has the following:

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef630000 irq 39
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17
```

Likewise, `lspci -v | grep -A5 -i "audio"` says:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at ef630000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at ef080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

So I know my sound cards are there. I've also confirmed that nothing is muted in alsamixer.

`aplay -l` produces:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've run `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`, as well.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling audio packages recommended here:
[Sound card stopped being detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085252/sound-card-stopped-being-detected)

I've tried everything here, too:
[No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after upgrade from 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029403/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-after-upgrade-from-16-04-lts)
In `pavucontrol` no cards are detected so I can't unmute `gnome-alsamixer`.

I've added `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to the end of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` also. I built my own computer and maybe there's something better than "auto"?

I tried removing `snd_hda_intel` with `pulseaudio -k && sudo service alsa-utils stop && sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel && sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel && sudo service alsa-utils start && pulseaudio -D` but couldn't because it was in use.

I'm out of ideas. :/

## Edit

Here's the output of `dmesg` for "snd_hda_intel":

```
[    5.333219] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.333703] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    5.333708] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    5.359714] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC1150: SKU not ready 0x00000000
```

And for "audio":

```
    [    5.333708] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    5.359714] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC1150: SKU not ready 0x00000000
[    5.360474] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1150: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    5.360475] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.360476] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.360477] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.360477] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    5.360478] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.360479] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    5.360480] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    5.360481] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[    5.382505] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
--
[   35.360044] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 4
[   37.069091] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

And I ran the Ac instructions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide

```
$ echo "Sound cards recognized by the system:"; lspci -nn | grep --color=none '\[04[80][13]\]'; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel modules: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel drivers in use: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done
Sound cards recognized by the system:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:8ca0]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f1] (rev a1)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:8ca0]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f1] (rev a1)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:8ca0]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f1] (rev a1)
```

## Edit 2

Here's the output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm        1934 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  gdm        1934 F.... pulseaudio
```

Comment: Please edit your post including the output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/* `

Comment: I've updated the post with the output as requested!

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri, I added the output to the post. Could you help me interpret it? Sorry, I'm not sure how to tag you...
https://askubuntu.com/users/856659/abu-ahmed-al-khatiri

Comment: Did you edit any pulseaudio config files in /etc before the upgrade?

Comment: I'm sorry for late responses, i don't have idea. Still finding the main problem

Comment: @life-on-mars , it was a few years (2017?), but it's totally possible I had edited the pusleaudio config files. Unfortunately (stupidly) I didn't make any sort of backup before upgrading (it's my netflix/coding on remote servers/DVR machine) and my understanding is they're overwritten when you upgrade.

Comment: Probably your alsa cannot access the module to choose the audio client. Try to reinstall the module : `sudo apt install build-essential linux-hheaders(uname -r) module-assistant alsa-ssource ,and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure alsa-source`. When a big blue dialog box appears, choose 'Yes' to compile the package maintainers and then 'Yes' again for debugging. Finally pick the driver you want . Lets we see the result.

Comment: **edited** : `sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers(uname -r) module-assistant alsa-source` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure alsa-source`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up running `sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-\`uname -r\` module-assistant alsa-source` because the terminal didn't like the parentheses. I'm not 100% that I successfully selected the correct sound card driver. I tried to select hda-intel, but the alsa GUI quit without a message. Is that the expected behavior? In any case, after rebooting, the sound output in Settings is unchanged.

Comment: Assuming I can't solve this until the .deb is built for the Intel HDA card for 18.04 (below), would using a USB "driver" bypass the issue?

Comment: @GenesRus My first idea here would be that PA is the culprit. How config files are updated changes sometimes, so I wouldn't be so sure they are simply overwritten. Try with default settings. Otherwise, my next step would be if the problem persists when booting from a LiveCD. If audio works there, the simplest solution would be to backup /home and do a clean install.

Comment: @life-on-mars, clean install it is. The audio works great on my USB boot drive (plus Chrome now opens, which was an equally annoying separate problem post-upgrade despite purging and reinstalling), so I'm just going to go that route. Thanks for the suggestion!