# Sound card stopped getting detected after ran out of battery

Tags: drivers, sound, 19.10, firmware

My laptop ran out of battery. I plugged it and boot it up again but the audio card is not getting detected anymore after boot. 
The only sound output listed is a dummy output.

Already tried reinstalling pulseaudio and solutions similar to the ones in the follwoing answer [Sound card stopped being detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085252/sound-card-stopped-being-detected)

If I boot up from live session on a USB, I won't have a problem.
I have reformatted my Ubuntu partition and installed it again but the problem persists.

output of: `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8  
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 863f  
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16  
Memory at 6043118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
Memory at 6043000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl       
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday, I am running Pop OS on a Dell Inspiron and installed some system updates. Later on the day my battery ran out and after plugging in and rebooting my soundcard could not be detected.
I found that kernel 5.3.0-7642 somehow broke the detection of my soundcard so I booted into a older kernel and voila, sound working again.

You can change the kernel by holding `ESC` during the boot procedure and selecting an older kernel.

Hope this helps!