# upgraded to 18.04 and pulseaudio shows only surround profiles

Tags: upgrade, pulseaudio

I always had terrible experiences when upgrading ubuntu versions, but somehow I am always tempted to do so! Hence, I attempted to upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04.
Several problems occurred, most of them solved but I still have problem with pulse audio.
I have an UMC404 audio card which used to run smoothly out of the box in 16.04.
After the upgrade pulseaudio (pavucontrol) shows only one profile (surround 4.0) of my UMC404 card whereas in 16.04 it had lots of them.The same appears in the config tab too. I am interested in the simple analogue output.
Any ideas of how I can restore this? I tried reinstalling pulseaudio but nothing happened.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032431/ubuntu-18-04-no-sound-card-detected

Comment: no, none of the suggestions worked for me. Somehow it picks only the surround 4.0 profile

Answer (score 0):

I also tried purge/uninstall both alsa and pulse audio, delete .config/pulse but still no change. Somehow pulseaudio/alsa pick up only this profile from some other part of the system.