# Intel 631xESB/632xESB High Definition Audio 20.04 Modules

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, soundcard

I'm trying to get audio to work on an old Mac Pro running 20.04 server. When I run `aplay -l` I get:

```
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

But when I run `lspci -v | grep -i audio` I get:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB High Definition Audio Controller (rev 09)
```

To me this indicates the system can see the sound card but doesn't have the right modules?

I tried re-installing the moduels using

```
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
```

I'm looking to get a little more guidance on were I should look to try and correct my sound issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my issue. [momsab's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032431/ubuntu-18-04-no-sound-card-detected) solution worked for me!

I'm assuming one of the packages in:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

solved my issue.